# Apache configuration doesn't update on restart

Tags: apache2, lamp

I'm running a LAMP development server with
Apache/2.4.41 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (5.11.0-38-generic).

When I modify apache or php configuration files such as apache2.conf or php.ini and then run
`service apache2 restart`
or
`systemctl restart apache2`
I'd expect the changes to apply, but they don't.

I've also tried `service reload apache2` just in case and also tried just waiting a few minutes, but the only thing that works is if I reboot the system.

I know the apache server restarts, because when I run `systemctl status apache2` the it's always active since the last time I ran either command.

How can I make sure the changes are applied when I restart apache?

Comment: Is it possible you have a browser cache hanging on for this application? Have you tried clearing your browser cache or using a "private" session?

Comment: Tried it just now and it still doesn't work, but what's even stranger is that I've tried it by switching php versions with ```a2dismod``` and ```a2enmod``` and phpinfo() gives different results than ```php -v```, but non of them are the last version I set.

Comment: Ok, I've realised the CLI has different configuration files, so what I wrote in the previous comment probably isn't relevant, but the config used by apache still doesn't update only on reboot.